# Difference between capacity miss and conflict miss

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture, cpu-cache

Premise:

1. Two types of cache miss:  capacity miss, conflict miss\
2. Cache contains only 2 sets, SET 1 and SET 2

Problem:

If data A maps to SET 1 and it doesn't exist in SET 1 while SET 1 is fully occupied and SET 2 is *not* fully occupied, I know this case is called conflict miss. But what should it be called if the same case but entire cache is fully occupied? Is it capacity miss or conflict miss? Once the cache is fully occupied, conflict miss will never happen?

Comment: Note that you can and should use Markdown for formatting your posts.

Answer (score 2):

It will be capacity miss because capacity miss means that your cache is full and there is no way to accommodate the data A.
Yes it means Once the cache is fully occupied, conflict miss will never happen.